# Why there are not 4 tangents from a point to a hyperbola or ellipse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, tangent-line

The equation of a tangent to a ellipse (x²/a²)+(y²/b²)=1 can be written as y=mx±√(a²m²+b²) ,where m is the slope of the tangent, now if this tangent passes through a specific point outside the ellipse, we can get a quadratic equation in terms of m, solving which will give us 2 values of m for the 2 tangents drawn to the ellipse from that point, but, there is also a "±" term before √(a²m²+b²) so each value of m would give 2 tangents corresponding to it? Then why we say that only 2 tangents can be drawn from a point to a ellipse?

There is a similarly titled question that already exists, but, does not specifically clarify the point I am asking.
Thank you.

Comment: You claim that “[t]he equation of a tangent to a ellipse can be written as $y=mx\pm\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$”. What are $m$, $a$, and $b$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos , I have editted it, check now

Comment: The two solutions you get by solving the quadratic equation correspond to the pair of values obtained from the $\pm$ in the formula.

Comment: same slope does not mean it passes from the same point. for a perticular slope elipse has 2 tangents but they are parallel to each other therefore from 1 point only 2 tangents can be drawn

Answer (score 2):

Standard Coordinate Geometry approach:

To find the equations of the tangents from an external point $(\alpha, \beta)$ to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.
[image]
We let the equation of the tangent be $y=mx+c$.

Putting $y=mx+c$ into $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and using $\Delta = 0$, we get $$c^2=a^2m^2+b^2.$$

To find the values of $m$ and $c$, we solve

$$c^2=a^2m^2+b^2  \tag{1}$$
and
$$\beta=m\alpha+c  \tag{2}$$

From $(1), (2)$, we have $$(\beta - m \alpha)^2=a^2m^2+b^2.$$

This is a quadratic equation in $m$ and hence in general has $2$ solutions in $m$.

But for each value of $m$ obtained,  equation $(2)$, i.e. $$c=\beta - m \alpha$$
will give only one single value of $c$.

Comment: but what if we try obtaining the final value of c for a given m from equation 2? Then will we not get 2 values of c for a particular m?

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee Do you mean finding the value of $c$ from $c^2=a^2m^2+b^2$? Of course we will correspondingly obtain $2$ values of $c$. Let's say we obtain $c=3$ or $c=4$. But only one of them will satisfy $c=\beta - m \alpha$. Thus there can only be one final answer.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying, I got it now